# how to recover deleted 'which protoc'?

Tags: ubuntu, protocol-buffers, apt-get

I was trying to remove libprotoc 3.0, then I followed a wrong command and deleted `which protoc` by this command `rm 'which protoc'`. I am facing a lot of errors related to protobuf. I wanted to install the following :

```
apt-get protobuf-compiler

E: Invalid operation protobuf-compiler
```

Does anyone have any solution? Thanks

Comment: First, you need to give an operation to apt-get: `apt-get install protobuf-compiler`. Second, it has nothing to do with python :D

Comment: You deleted `which protoc`?

Comment: Are those perhaps backticks ?

Comment: @Tagc yes, unfortunately

Comment: @BloodyD thanks for your recommendation. it is not working

Comment: @S.EB What I mean is, that doesn't make sense. You can't use `rm` to delete a command. The command `rm 'which protoc'` would just attempt to remove a file called 'which protoc'.

Comment: I think he used other parenthesis.... so `which protoc` was evaluated by his bash and returned the location of `protoc` executable, which then was removed. Nevertheless, @S.EB what is your error?

Comment: Try a reinstall: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall protobuf-compiler`.